# Searching and Filters - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

My Scenario:
I have a database on Google Sheets with peoples names and information along with that.
I have found two methods of searching for data belonging to people.

The first one is this:

```
=IF($L$28="","",IFERROR(FILTER('SheetName'!E:K, REGEXMATCH('SheetName'!E:E, L28)),"No Results"))
```

What this line does is search for anything that includes what is in L28. However, it is case sensitive - and I don't want it to be case sensitive.

The second is:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('SheetName'!E:K,'SheetName'!E:E=M3),"No Results")
```

What this line does is search for what ever is in M3, but it is not case sensitive. However, for my use case I need to know if it includes a segment of text.
For example: I search for 'AD'
And I should get these results

```
!AD
AD!
AD
ADdictive
aDdictive
Addition
```

So the solution I am looking for:

- Not Case Sensitive
- Searches for anything containing a peice of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A1:A, SEARCH("*mango*", A1:A)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem!